# git cannot go to the re-branched master branch

Tags: git, github

In our git repository, something weird happend in a commit by a person A and hundreds of files changed with `<<<< or ==== or >>>>` marks in the content. Not knowing it, I and person A added a couple of commits after that. Then, after finding out what happend, I made the master branch go back to the correct commit just before the accident commit and committed the updated files again.  I remember I used these commands to go back to the last correct commit (and I added a commit after that).

```
git reset --hard 2d958ff...
git push --force
```

In my another computer, when I do `git pull origin master` and `git checkout origin/master`, everything looked normal(meaning the commits from the accident commit are not shown in the `git log` history).

This morning my coleague (he is the person A), said he can't go back to the new master branch, so I went to his desk and tried. The `git log` showed it is in a commit forwarded from the accident commit. So I did `git reset HEAD` for two files (for those it gave us a message that they are unmerged) and did `git checkout` for those two files(to see no difference in the local files). Then I did `git checkout b65fc37` to come to the last recovered master branch. This is what I saw in his computer (this is the same that I see in my computer).

```
commit b65fc37.... (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)    <=== newly recovered master
Author: Chan Kim <ckim@etri.re.kr>
Date:   Wed Aug 2 18:14:00 2023 +0900

        o comment 3

(no commits that were cut shown here)   

commit 2d958ff....              <== the last correct commit
Author: Chan Kim <ckim@etri.re.kr>
Date:   Mon Jul 24 14:18:01 2023 +0900

        o comment 2


commit 3eec7dd....
Author: Chan Kim <ckim@etri.re.kr>
Date:   Mon Jul 24 09:59:12 2023 +0900

        o comment 1
```

The problem is, when I do `git branch` in my computer, I see I'm in the master branch, but when I do `git branch` in person A's computer, it shows it is detachted from any branch (with same `git log` history) and if I do `git checkout master`, it goes to the commit which is forwarded from the accident commit(which was not shown in `git log` history). What is happening and how can I checkout master branch in my colleague's computer?

Comment: Once you know the commit sha, on the other computer, do `git checkout master` and then `git reset --hard COMMITSHA`. If they don't have the commit, make sure you've pushed, and then have the other person do `git fetch --all`. And finally, make sure everyone has their bash prompt configured to show the git branch in the prompt. There's no point using git without this feature. The other person got into a detached head state without understanding it.

Comment: @AndyRay Hi, that seems to have worked! Thank you! (if you post an answer with the same comment, I can choose it as the selected answer)

Comment: For others : to show git branch name in bash prompt, it's worth a see!.  https://thucnc.medium.com/how-to-show-current-git-branch-with-colors-in-bash-prompt-380d05a24745

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `git reset --hard COMMITSHA` to reset a branch to a specific commit. `git checkout` modifies the index, and will only switch the current `HEAD` pointer if you checkout a branch. `git checkout b65fc37` will put you into a detached head state (not on any branch), rather than set the current branch's commit to that SHA.

Once you know the commit sha, on the other computer, do git checkout master and then `git reset --hard COMMITSHA`.

If they don't have the commit, make sure you've pushed, and then have the other person do `git fetch --all`.

And this isn't directly related to your question, but, make sure everyone has their Bash prompt configured to show the git branch in the prompt. There's no point using git without this feature. The other person got into a detached head state without understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting local branches and force-pushing does *not* have an effect on other clones of the same repository and does not magically remove commits from other people's computers.

After you have force-pushed a reset or rewritten history, anybody with a clone needs to fetch and perform the same reset or rebase their local commits.

In your case, your colleague will want to reset their local branch, then fetch, then fast-forward, merge or rebase onto the "current" commits from the remote. Alternatively, have them delete their local branch and recreate it from the remote one.